# Gmail Android HTML Email resizing Issue

Tags: android, html, css, email, litmus

I am building an HTML Email for a client, however, I am having issues in Gmail. I have tested in litmus and its working in most if not all clients apart from Gmail Android. 
It looks like Gmail is resizing the background image however isn't changing the font-size. I have tried media queries, common Gmail fixes with spacers and my background image is using the bulletproof background design.

I also tried changing the font-size for the terms and conditions, however, it does nothing in Gmail. 
The biggest issue is the main paragraph in the middle and the white text at the bottom of the image. I would just have all of it as an image, however, I need the links to be available.

I wouldn't mind even if the img being forced at 100% on Gmail with a scroll bar or if I could force the text to be the correct size. Help would be much appreciated. Check out the codepen at - https://codepen.io/habiba29/pen/eQZqpd

I have tried the usual

```
<!-- prevent Gmail on iOS font size manipulation -->
<div class="gmailfix" style="font:15px courier;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;line-height:0;white-space:nowrap">
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
</div>
<div style="display:none;font:15px courier;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;line-height:0;white-space:nowrap">
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
</div>
```